# cloudfront redirect to internal elb without changing the browser url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a request that my website will be reached with one domain for every AZ.
Based on a customer name I will forward the request to the correct ELB on the correct AZ.

for example: https://www.youtubo.com/customer_name
Check where is the region the customer is in: US/EU... using keyValueStore  every customer will have the elb to redirect to.

The browser link should stay the same, meaning the URL should not chang so this will be transparent to the user

I tried this sample:

```
    if (countryCode === country) {
        var response = {
            statusCode: 302,
            statusDescription: 'Found',
            headers:
                { "location": { "value": newurl } }
            }

        return response;
    }
```

But this is changing the client URL - how should I do it to forward the request to an internal resource and the browser link will stay the same?

Comment: What you describe is not a "redirect". A redirect is an HTTP concept that will always change the browser URL. What you want is for CloudFront to use different origins based on the source country. You'll need to do something like this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/using-amazon-cloudfront-with-multi-region-amazon-s3-origins/